# How to model a condenser (heat exchanger) where both streams are two fluid mixtures?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, chemical-engineering, heat-exchanger, multiphase-flow

As mentioned I would like to model a heat exchanger (using Python). In this case, the condenser/hx streams are both a mixture of O2 and N2

**These are known for both streams:**

- Inlet temperature
- Inlet flowrate (moles)
- Inlet composition (fraction of each component in each phase. Gas/liquid)
- The approach temperature of the HX is also assumed to be 5K

**We cannot assume that condensation will occur. So two cases are:**

1. condensation of one stream occurs
2. condensation does not occur

As I am modelling this mathematically, I would hope to set up a function in this form:

**INPUTS:**

- Inlet temperature 1 and 2
- Inlet liquid flow 1 and 2
- Inlet vapour flow 1 and 2
- Inlet vapour composition 1 and 2
- Inlet liquid composition 1 and 2
- The assumed approach temperature

**OUTPUTS:**

- Outlet temperature of stream 1 and 2
- Outlet liquid flow
- Outlet vapour flow
- Outlet composition of each phase
- I have equations for enthalpy of each compound also so we can calculate the outlet enthalpy too

**ASSUMED KNOWLEDGE:**

- I have equations for heat capacity, enthalpy, heat of vaporisation of both compounds (in function format). These take temperature as input
- I have Antoine equations/Raoults law implemented for both compounds (in function format also

I am hoping to get either a reference to an algorithm on how to do this (video, textbook, etc), or the algorithm itself

I am also available at any time to answer any questions.

Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the [NTU method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTU_method#:~:text=The%20Number%20of%20Transfer%20Units,Mean%20Temperature%20Difference%20(LMTD).), which you can tailor to your needs depending on the type of heat exchanger. However IMHO your question needs a bit more focus.

Comment: So could both streams condense?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will look into the NTU method I haven't heard of it. And Solar Mike, no only one stream can condense. Also NMech please explain how I can add focus to the question